# Intersection of n hyperplanes in projective space of dimension n is not empty

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, algebraic-curves, projective-space

I want to prove the following:

> Let $H_1,\dots,H_n$ be $n$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^n =\mathbb{P}^n \mathbb{C}$. Then $\cap_{i=1}^n H_i$ is not empty.

Please be noted that this is an exercise from William Fulton's *Algebraic Curves*, the section of projective Nullstensatz, Q4.12.

I know this statement is equivalent to the following:

> Let $I$ be a homogeneous ideal in $\mathbb{C}[X_1,...,X_n]$. Let $M$ be the ideal generated by $X_1,...,X_n$. Then if $I$ contains $M^k$ for some $k$, $I$ can not be generated by less than $n$ forms of degree $1$.

I have tried to use induction on $n$ to prove the  question, the case $n=0,1,2$ is obvious.

Assume the result for $n=l$. For $n=l+1$:
If $I$ is generated by $f_1,...,f_l$, then by the induction hypothesis, we may assume $X_1^k$ and $X_2^k$ cannot be generated by $f_1,...,f_{l-1}$ for all $k$, but I could not proceed to find a contradiction.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In case it helps, the result can be seen with elementary linear algebra: A hyperplane in $\mathbf{CP}^{n}$ corresponds to a homogeneous linear equation (unique up to scaling) in $(n + 1)$ variables. An intersection of $n$ hyperplanes therefore corresponds to the solution set of a homogeneous linear system of $n$ equations in $(n + 1)$ variables, which admits a non-trivial solution.

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your algebraic reformulation of the question.

Since $I$ contains a power of $M$ we have $\sqrt I=M$. (In other words, $M$ is the only minimal ideal over $I$.) This shows $\operatorname{height}I=\operatorname{height}M=n$. If $I$ can be generated by $m<n$ elements then, by [Krull Intersection Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem), we get $n=\operatorname{height}I\le m$, a contradiction.

Comment: I see, so you have proved the general case that $f_i$ need not be linear forms

Comment: @chankifung Actually the minimal number of homogeneous generators and the minimal number of generators are equal for a homogeneous ideal.